# Does & have a special meaning in HDFS file naming?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I made a directory by the name of "original&normalized" but can't seem to delete it. Every time I run `hadoop fs -rm -r original&normalized` or `hadoop fs -rm -r -f original&normalized`, I get:

```
-bash: normalized: command not found
-bash-4.1$ rm: `original': No such file or directory
```

What's going on here? How can I delete the directory?

Comment: This is probably because `&` is interpreted as a special character in this case. Try to quote the folder path `fs -rm -r "original&normalized"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked

Comment: You should also be able to simply escape the `&` character using `fs -rm -r original\&normalized`